# Magento2: Update to 2.3.2. changed order IDs, want to change it back

Tags: php, magento, magento-2.3

I recently ran an update from Magento 2.2.6 to Magento 2.3.2. Worked out sort of well, except now my Order ID's are different.

Old order ID: 10000410686
New order ID: 100004**0000**10686

As you can see I got 4 bonus zeroes.

I understand that the number before the '4' is the store prefix. I just can't figure out how to remove the four zeros again. The available stackoverflow posts regarding this problem did not help me any further.

In summary my questions: 
1. How do I revert back to the 'old' order ID system. 
2. Is there any clean and safe way to adjust the orders placed under the 'new' order ID layout?
3. Any commands that need to be run afterward? (reindex, cache:flush etc.) before the changes to take effect?

I kindly thank you for any helpful answers.

Comment: Check this one : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245312/how-to-change-the-order-numbers-prefix-of-a-specific-store-magento2

Comment: Hi Rakesh, thank you for the help. It does clarify how the sequence system works, but not exactly how I can remove the four zeroes.

Comment: I solved this with adding the following to the app/etc di.xml     <type name="Magento\Framework\DB\Sequence\SequenceInterface">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="pattern" xsi:type="string">%s%'.04d%s</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with adding the following to the app/etc di.xml and run setup/di:compile afterwards

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\DB\Sequence\SequenceInterface">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pattern" xsi:type="string">%s%'.04d%s</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```